# Floating button Android Lollipop

Tags: android, button, styles, android-5.0-lollipop, floating

I have a style so defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval"
            android:dither="true">

            <solid 
                android:color="#CCFF0000" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval"
            android:dither="true">

            <solid android:color="#F44336" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I would try to draw this -> [image]

But i can draw the shadow. I can't use android:elevation because i would maintain compability with previous versions of android. How can i simulate the shadow as in the picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use elevation I suggest you to use a Shadow's picture as: [https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/blob/master/library/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/fab_bg_mini.png][1]